# Interior ,exterior of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Circle divides the plane in which it is lying into three parts ,i.e., interior , exterior and circle. 
So I want to ask do we include circle in interior or exterior part of circle or both?

Comment: Usually you would say "circle" if you just want the outline, and "disc" if you want the outline along with the stuff in the middle.

Comment: @Joppy Oh, ok. I got confused with my native language: in elementary euclidean geometry we call "cerchio" the disk and "circonferenza" the circle (which is weird, for not even in French it is like this).

Comment: If question says interior of a circle, do we take x^2+y^2< or<=r^2 ?

Comment: @KaSikh If the question says interior of circle, we take $x^2 + y^2 < $

Comment: I also think the same. But my book is taking less than or equal to

Comment: Definitions like the one you mention often differ among books. Stay with your book and get over it.